# Where should I post questions about compilers' behavior?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to know where I should post the question *[Why is GCC exchanging rax and xmm0 registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745125/why-is-gcc-exchanging-rax-and-xmm0-registers)*.

Considering it was voted as off-topic, I understood that this question is not a programming trouble, but a question about a behavior, so which of the Stack Exchange communities should I use for questions about compilers?

Comment: The question was closed because it "... was caused by a problem that **can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error", presumably because you said: "I did what Jester told me and added -O3, this way those instructions disappeared".

Comment: @muru It's true that when I did what Jester told me the instructions disappeared, but what I'd like to know was why GCC was adding those extra instructions when I used -mtune=native, that was not clear to me, anyway so StackOverflow keeps as the right place to make this kind of question?

Comment: IMO, yes. Questions on compiler behaviour have been asked before. You should probably edit your question to indicate that you'd still like an answer for when you're not using `-O3` with GCC.

Comment: SO is generally not a good place for questions which are answered by speculations.  Once in a blue moon you get someone who actually knows the answer to stop by, but more often you just get a list of different people's guesses.  I'd contact the GCC team to get an actual answer as to the specific implementation details.

Comment: Thank you @Won't I thought that this was a hard question even for the best programmers at SO, I'm gonna try to contact GCC team in order to receive a better answer.